# HTML One time use page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I want it so on a website once the user signs up/requests a password recovery the email address of the account they have requested is sent an email with a 1 time password set page with a time-out.

The way I can think of doing it is having a database table with a random access key and an expire time.

- An incorrect key and the page doesn't run.
- If the key is correct but time has expired offer to send another.
- If both correct on page access remove key from database table.

Unless I am using the wrong key words I can't find anything about it on google.

Is this a secure method or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Maybe send him a link with some kind of id="" where the id will be read on that page and creates a cookie. You can check both the id or cookie if it match with the one which got created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds good to me.

i would do 2 cases:

1) "url-key thingie" not in db, or in db but expired ---> Process as "page is either unavailable or expired, recheck email."

2) link hits an active timelimit reference, display page via SSL. use PDO.

including Captcha not a bad idea. google Captcha.